# Find manual changes in ConfigMap when working with "kubectl apply"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster and do all my deployments in a declarative manner, by executing the "apply" command in CI/CD pipeline.

"Apply" works in such a way that it merges the state of an object with the manifest that came with the command. As the result, you may make manual changes - for example, add a new key-value to a ConfigMap and "apply" will leave it intact, even though this key doesn't exist in source code.

So I wonder, how can I detect such issues? Doing "delete" and "create" is not an option since it disrupts the availability. I don't want to change deployment from "apply" since it's production. I just to find manual modifications in a namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure if kubectl can give you a "manual applied changes in cluster"-result. You can however, fetch the resource from the api, and diff it using a tool like `kubediff` with your local changes in your git for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[kubediff](https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff)** is what you are looking for.

You can run it as a command-line tool e.g.:

```
$ ./kubediff k8s
Checking ReplicationController 'kubediff'
 *** .spec.template.spec.containers[0].args[0]: '-repo=https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff' != '-repo=https://github.com/<your github repo>'
Checking Secret 'kubediff-secret'
Checking Service 'kubediff'
```

or as a service inside K8s cluster. This mode also gives you a simple UI showing the output.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl patch` or `kubectl replace` are suitable for your use case. Take a look to this [blog](https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-apply-replace-patch/) which better explain the difference between them.

If you always want to update configmap to whatever is in your manifest, then go for replace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure about changing the deployment command from "apply" in production. Is there a way to get the diff, to detect manual changes? I'm thinking maybe "last applied configuration" might help.